# How does Azure DevOps(appear to) keep you logged in after clearing browser cache?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-devops

Here are the steps to reproduce exactly what I saw:

1. Open a task in Azure DevOps
2. Clear browser cache
3. Add a comment to the task and click save

The comment saves without issue and you are able to continue using DevOps normally. My expected behavior is that I would be logged out and must log back in, generally that is what happens when you clear cache.

How does Azure DevOps seamlessly keep you logged in like this?

Comment: authenticated cookie.

Answer (score 0):

> How does Azure DevOps(appear to) keep you logged in after clearing browser cache?

I could not reproduce this issue on my side with Google Chrome.

When I save the comment on the task, it will pop-up authentication window:

[image]

So, Azure DevOps Will not keep logged in.

You could try this in other browser.